# How to find all the files that a program opens/read/write?

Tags: macos

Just wondering if there's a free software for mac that checks which files are opened/read or written during the execution of a given software and return them like a three graph. I'm sure I saw something similar in past but I can't remember its name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be thinking of [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start), but it only shows changed files (not those just being read), and shows all changes not just those by a specific program.

Other possible not-quite answers: in Activity Monitor, you can "inspect" a process and (if you own it) see what files it has open. In Terminal, you can use the `lsof` command to list files opened by all of your processes (if you're an admin, you can use `sudo lsof` to see processes you don't own). Also check out the Terminal commands `fs_usage`, `filebyproc.d`, `opensnoop`, and `rwsnoop`. Finally, if you have Xcode (Apple's developer tools suite), check out [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 2):

[fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) also has an option to include files that are just opened:

[image]

`opensnoop` prints files opened by processes:

```
sudo opensnoop -n processname
```

Answer (score 0):

For me on macOS Ventura, `opensnoop` was not really working, however `lsof` did the job.

```
top -l 1     #find the process ID of the FortiClientUpdater
sudo lsof -p 18592     #look for a suspicious entry, in my case the last one
open /private/var/folders/w3/my9vhvh48xjb4h0059bc_ssh0000gn/T/fctupdate/obj_1_TGiK3k
```

There it was, the temporary location of the installer.