# trace all file opens of executable with command line on macos

Tags: strace

(related to [How to find all the files that a program opens/read/write?](https://superuser.com/questions/463519/how-to-find-all-the-files-that-a-program-opens-read-write) , but unfortunately the answers are obsolete.  it seems that security and multicore concerns have been mucking around with the solutions over iterations of macos.)

Let's say that I have become suspicious about a macos command line program, or I want to learn what, say, `clang` (`gcc`) reads when it does its job.  so, I want to run

```
$ ftrace "gcc a.c" &> all-files-accessed-by-gcc-compiling-a.c
```

which I can later `grep` for file names, e.g., did it access any of my files in `.ssh`.

is this easy?  some kind of strace or ktrace or dtruss invokation?